# Unwanted whitespace on some screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My code is responsive to many screen resolutions but on an iPad and a Kindle Fire HDX , there is a large whitespace below the footer.

This is how it looks on an iPad
[image]

And this how it looks on Kindle Fire HDX
[image]

Here is link to my code on codepen
https://codepen.io/stel/pen/BGMXxq

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Mess Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<div class='logo-container'>
<img src='mess-order-logo.svg' alt='application logo'>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-bars" id='menu-bar'></i>
</nav>

<div class='time'>
<p>Monday 26 November 2018</p>
<p>TODAY'S OFFERS</p>
</div>

<div id=meal-parent-container>

<div class='meal-container'>
<div class='meal-img'>
<img src='jollof.jpg' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
</div>
<div class=meal-description>
<span>Jollof Rice with Chicken</span>
<button>
<span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class='meal-container'>
<div class='meal-img'>
<img src='gobe.jpeg' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
</div>
<div class=meal-description>
<span>Fried Plantain with Beans</span>
<button>
<span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>


<div class='meal-container'>
<div class='meal-img'>
<img src='plain-rice.jpg' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
</div>
<div class=meal-description>
<span>Plain Rice with Chicken</span>
 <button>
<span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class='meal-container'>
<div class='meal-img'>
<img src='banku-and-Tilapia.jpg' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
</div>
<div class=meal-description>
<span>Banku With Tilapia</span>
<button>
<span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button> 
</div>
  </div>
<div class='meal-container'>
  <div class='meal-img'>
  <img src='Fufu-and-fish.jpg' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
  </div>
  <div class=meal-description>
  <span>Fufu with Light Soup</span>
  <button>
  <span class='order'>Order Now</span>
  </button>
  </div>
  </div>   
  </div>

  <div class='special-offers'>
  <p>Special Offers</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
Made with love &copy; 2018
  </footer>
  </body>
  </html>



body,html{
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

body{
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: #136a8a;*/  /* fallback for old browsers
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);
}

nav{
  background-color: #16222A;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size:160%;
}

#menu-bar{
  padding: 1.2%;
  color:#999999;
}

.logo-container{
  width:20%;
}
.logo-container img{
  max-width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.meal-container{
  background-color:white;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:1.3em;
  padding:0.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
.meal-img{
  width:40%;
}

.meal-img img{
  max-width:100%;
}

.meal-description{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:flex-start;
 justify-content: space-between;
  width:50%;
}

#meal-parent-container{

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 5%;

}

.time, .special-offers{
  background-color:white;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:1.3em;
  padding:0.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  text-align: center;
}

.special-offers{
  margin-bottom: 1.3em;
}

button{
  padding: 0.8em;
  color: white;
  background: #16222A;
  border: 0px;
}

footer{

  background: #16222A;
  padding:1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 120%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:410px) {

  .time{
      margin-top:1.5em;
  }

  .meal-description{
    padding:0.7em;
  }

  .logo-container{
    width:18%;
  }

}
@media screen and (min-width:430px) {

  .time{
      margin-top:1.8em;
  }

  .meal-description{
    padding:1em;
  }

  .logo-container{
    width:16%;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {

  .time{
      margin-top:2.3em;
      width:70%;
  }
  .meal-container{
    width:80%;
}
.meal-img{
  max-width: 37%;
}
  .meal-description{
    padding:1.2em;
  }

  .special-offers{
    width: 80%;

  }

  .logo-container{
    width:16%;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
#meal-parent-container{
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.meal-container{
  width:45%;
}


.time{
    margin-top:2.6em;
}

.logo-container{
  width:12%;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {


.time{
    margin-top:2.9em;
}

.logo-container{
  width:10%;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {


  .time{
      width:60%;
  }

  .special-offers{
    width: 70%;

  }

.logo-container{
  width:8%;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {


  .time{
      width:50%;
  }

  .special-offers{
    width: 60%;

  }

.logo-container{
  width:6%;
}

}
```

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your content is just not enough to fill the whole viewport. You could position your footer absolutely. Or give a min-height to your content. Or use flexbox to let your content area grow.

Here a pen to play with a flexbox solution: https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/zMbYxL

There is a flex-grow on a new wrapper `main` for your content.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

body {
  background: #136a8a;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #267871, #136a8a);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-top: 40px
}

nav {
  background-color: #16222A;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 160%;
}

#menu-bar {
  padding: 1.2%;
  color: #999999;
}

.logo-container {
  width: 20%;
}

.logo-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.meal-container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1.3em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.meal-img {
  width: 40%;
}

.meal-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.meal-description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
}

#meal-parent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.time,
.special-offers {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1.3em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  text-align: center;
}

.special-offers {
  margin-bottom: 1.3em;
}

button {
  padding: 0.8em;
  color: white;
  background: #16222A;
  border: 0px;
}

footer {
  background: #16222A;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 120%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:410px) {
  .time {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
  }
  .meal-description {
    padding: 0.7em;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 18%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:430px) {
  .time {
    margin-top: 1.8em;
  }
  .meal-description {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 16%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
  .time {
    margin-top: 2.3em;
    width: 70%;
  }
  .meal-container {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .meal-img {
    max-width: 37%;
  }
  .meal-description {
    padding: 1.2em;
  }
  .special-offers {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 16%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  #meal-parent-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .meal-container {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .time {
    margin-top: 2.6em;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 12%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
  .time {
    margin-top: 2.9em;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 10%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
  .time {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .special-offers {
    width: 70%;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 8%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
  .time {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .special-offers {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 6%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class='logo-container'>
      <img src='https://image.ibb.co/iMNFxy/noknoknok.png' alt='application logo'>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" id='menu-bar'></i>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class='time'>
      <p>Monday 26 November 2018</p>
      <p>TODAY'S OFFERS</p>
    </div>

    <div id=meal-parent-container>

      <div class='meal-container'>
        <div class='meal-img'>
          <img src='https://image.ibb.co/kuVDjd/noknok.png' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
        </div>
        <div class=meal-description>
          <span>Jollof Rice with Chicken</span>
          <button>
  <span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='meal-container'>
        <div class='meal-img'>
          <img src='https://image.ibb.co/kuVDjd/noknok.png' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
        </div>
        <div class=meal-description>
          <span>Fried Plantain with Beans</span>
          <button>
  <span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class='meal-container'>
        <div class='meal-img'>
          <img src='https://image.ibb.co/kuVDjd/noknok.png' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
        </div>
        <div class=meal-description>
          <span>Plain Rice with Chicken</span>
          <button>
  <span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='meal-container'>
        <div class='meal-img'>
          <img src='https://image.ibb.co/kuVDjd/noknok.png' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
        </div>
        <div class=meal-description>
          <span>Banku With Tilapia</span>
          <button>
  <span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class='meal-container'>
        <div class='meal-img'>
          <img src='https://image.ibb.co/kuVDjd/noknok.png' alt='picture of jollof rice'>
        </div>
        <div class=meal-description>
          <span>Fufu with Light Soup</span>
          <button>
  <span class='order'>Order Now</span>
</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class='special-offers'>
      <p>Special Offers</p>
    </div>

  </main>

  <footer>
    Made with love &copy; 2018
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: The flexbox solution works well for the iPad screen resolution but adds horizontal scrolling to the page on other screen resolutions so I think I'd go with positioning my footer absolutely.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't write the whole code for you. You have to position your elements within the main element. My sample was just about showing how to let the main content grow.

Comment: Get rid of the widths and use flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis for your card layout. There are some nice tutorials out there for card layouts with flexbox:
https://getflywheel.com/layout/flexbox-create-modern-card-design-layout/

Answer (score 0):

That is mainly because the content of the page does occupy all of the view space of the screen.

If you want the footer to stick to the bottom, you can add a fixed positioning to it in your css:

```
footer {
  background: #16222A;
  padding:1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 120%;

  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To offset the content so as to avoid it being covered by the footer, you can add the page content inside a container `div` a padding to the bottom of the container element:

```
<div class="container>
    ...
    <!-- Your page content -->
</div>
```

And in your CSS File:

```
,container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 60px; /* Adjust the value to match the height of the footer */
}
```

Comment: It works but on  some  screen resolutions, some of the content is covered by the footer and I can't seem to make them uncovered.

Comment: @StelDare I updated my answer with a possible fix. Let me the results.